# is it possible to make part of MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround component align left in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I have a card component that have three element:

- the channel profile image
- the channel title
- a button that show the channel subscribe status

now I am using a row component to show the three component, this is my full code:

```
return Card(
      key: Key(counter.value.id.toString()),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 20,
                    backgroundColor: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .primaryColor,
                    backgroundImage: backgroundImage,
                    foregroundImage:foregroundImage,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                      child: Text(
                          counter.value.subName,
                          softWrap: true,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (isFav.value == 1)
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8.0, left: 10),
                      child: ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: 50,
                          height: 30.0,
                          child: RaisedButton.icon(
                            color: Theme
                                .of(context)
                                .primaryColor,
                            icon: Icon(
                              Feather.check_circle,
                              size: 16,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () =>
                                touchSub(
                                    counter.value.id.toString(), SubStatus.UNSUB),
                            label: Text("已订阅"),
                          )),
                    ),
                  if (isFav.value != 1)
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8.0, right: 1),
                      child: ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: 50,
                          height: 30.0,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            color: Theme
                                .of(context)
                                .primaryColor,
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                            onPressed: () =>
                                touchSub(
                                    counter.value.id.toString(), SubStatus.SUB),
                            child: Text("订阅"),
                          )),
                    )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child: Text(counter.value.intro,
                        softWrap: true,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

everything works perfect but have one problem, I want the channel title align left maybe look like better but now it align center of the card. I tried to add a align in text component like this:

```
child: Text(
      counter.value.subName,
      softWrap: true,
      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      )),
```

actually it did not make any difference. so I tried to tweak the `MainAxisAlignment` to `MainAxisAlignment.start`, but a new problem is the component show left to right, I want the subscribe button on the right position. For now I really did not know what should I to to make it as my expect. So what should I do to make:

profile image on the left and subscribe button on the right and title on the left but on the right of profile image? This is the status now:

[image]

the title is center but I want the title on left and follow the profile image.

Answer (score 0):

I added a sizebox in the flex component and expand the center component size:

```
SizedBox(
    width: screenWidth * 0.45,
    child: Flexible(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
        child: Text(counter.value.subName,
            softWrap: true,
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            )),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

it works, look like this:

[image]